# Java : clean up runnable object with socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a multi-threaded server application in Java.
Everything works fine  , but there's one little problem.
When I'm stopping the runnable which listens for incoming connection request  , the socket keeps existing . So my question is : How do I stop a runnable object and clean up all the objects made in this runnable ?

The code for stopping the thread:

```
Runnable tr = new Worldwide() ; 
        Thread thread = new Thread(tr) ;
        thread.start() ; 
        online =  true ;

        while (core.getServerSate()) {
            try{
            Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } ;
        thread.stop() ;
        thread.
        core.printToConsole("Server is offline now") ;
```

The Runnable code :

```
public class Worldwide implements Runnable  { 

Core core = Core.getInstance()  ; 

public Worldwide () {

}
@Override
public void  run() { 

    try {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port) ;

    core.printToConsole("Server is online") ; 
    core.printToConsole ( "listening on port :" +  server.getLocalPort()) ; 
    while (core.getServerSate() == true) {

        Socket client = server.accept() ; 
        Runnable tr = new ClientCommunication(client) ; 
        new Thread (tr).start() ;

    }

    }
    catch(Exception e ) {
        core.printToConsole ("An error occured while going online") ; 
        e.printStackTrace() ; 
    } 
    }
```

Thanks  , Tom

Comment: Do not use `Thread.stop`. This method has been deprecated. Instead, it's best to use `Thread.interrupt` and base your loop logic on the thread's interrupted state. And when you catch the interrupt, you'll need to propagate it.

Comment: I guess that won't work for me , because the loop stops at Socket client = server.accept() ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close the socket from the main thread. This will break the call to `accept` and cause it to throw an `IOException`. You can then exit the accept thread's `run` method from the catch of the `IOException`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But how can I close a socket from the main thread?

Comment: @tb96. You have to create the socket in the main thread and pass it to the worker thread. That way you have the socket object in both threads and you can call `accept` in the worker thread and `close` in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks  , this was the answer I needed :)

Comment: @tb96: Or an even better solution would be to put a method `stopServer` inside the class that implements `Runnable` and just call that method on the `tr` object. That way the main thread doesn't need to see the socket object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly close the ServerSocket by calling the [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29) -method of the socket. The best place to do this is in your `Worldwide`-class's `run`-method, in a `finally`-block (so the socket gets closed even if an exception occurs).